# What does DF__role_sett__custo__4589517F in SQL Server database mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have just inherited a database from another developer, and I have looked through the `sys.objects` table, filtering by constraints.

What does `DF__role_sett__custo__4589517F` mean - mainly the ID at the end of the string?

I know that `DF_role_sett_custo` means default constraint of `role_setting_customer`, but am not sure of the last ID `4589517f`.

Comment: I always thought it was there for randomness. I don't think its meaningful.

Comment: FYI, the first thing I recommend doing when inheriting databases is scripting out the entire structure into single files per object and include triggers, constraints, and indexes. We keep this in version control, but as an added benefit, it makes it easy to search and find things.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't name a constraint when it is created, SQL Server will assign it a random name based on the table and column. It appends a random number so that it doesn't clash with existing constraint names.

In almost all cases, it is best to name a constraint when it is created. It's then easier to refer to the constraint by name in other T-SQL statements.

For instance, in the following create statement

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.some_table(
   some_field INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(5)
);
```

The default constraint will be assigned a random name. In this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.some_table(
   some_field INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_some_table_some_field DEFAULT(5)
);
```

The default constraint will have the name you assigned to it (i.e. `DF_some_table_some_field`).

Comment: Always a **good idea** to explicitly name **all** constraints one creates - otherwise it gets a bit hairy, especially if you end up wanting to disable or drop one of them ....

Comment: @marc_s I agree, though I wrote *in almost all cases* because for temporary tables or table variables, naming the constraints isn't all that important.

Comment: @TT. so the ID '4589517F' is part of a random name that has been created for the particular constraint? What (if any) use would this have when using this constraint?

Comment: @Needabitofhelp **1** Yes. **2** There's no particular use.  `4589517F` is part of the constraint name. Each constraint has a name, whether one you assigned or whether it was assigned by SQL Server. Some T-SQL statements require that you name the constraint, e.g. what marc_s pointed out: disabling constraints or dropping constraints.